# I'm a having an error with my flutter code when I run it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

The error says CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, Object>>' in type cast). When I try to debug the code, it point me to line 18 with that error message. Kindly assist me with it. I'm new to flutter development.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestion;
  // const Quiz({super.key});

  Quiz({required this.questions, required this.answerQuestion, required this.questionIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] as String),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>).map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text'] as String);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code

Comment: That error seems to occure at the property "answers". Make sure that your maps have all a property called answer with value of type List<Map<String, Object>>.

Comment: @bface007 Thanks for your answer. I was able to figure it out and it's working perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you posted, the data is null.

Specifically, `questions[questionIndex]['answers']` is `null`. Try print out the data and see if you made any typo in the property name. You can do that by adding a `print(questions[questionIndex]['answers']);` before your `return Column(...)` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did as you suggested but still getting the error

Comment: @CyberEmperor What's the printout, did it print "null" in the console?

Comment: Yes please. it did print null

Comment: @CyberEmperor That's the problem. You should check your data and make sure it's not null.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Will go through it again